# How to get the value from another sheet with variable sheet name using Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to get the sheet name from a cell.

On image below I'm trying to get '4/2'!$AB60.

1. need to get the date which is 4/2 (cell D5)
2. combine it with !$AB60
3. now the cell D6 will have a formula value of '4/2'!$AB60
4. it will display the value.

Is there a way to formulate this instead of what I currently be doing, manually updating the each column dates (from C6 to AF6)? Is this even possible?

[image]

Comment: Why the google-apps-script tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula from the screenshot: `=JOIN(,LEFT(D5,LEN(D5),!$AB60)`

The problem with this formula is `!$AB60` as it is not a valid value, instead use `"!$AB60"` or use `=TO_TEXT(D5)&"!$AB60"`. To use the result of this formula as a cell reference use `INDIRECT`, i.e.:

```
=INDIRECT(TO_TEXT(D5)&"!$AB60")
```

Comment: may be `=INDIRECT("'"&TO_TEXT(D5)&"'!$AB60")`

Comment: Thanks but how about on the next row? How will be able to make it =INDIRECT(TO_TEXT(D5)&"!$AB61")

Comment: @MikeSteelson The formula in the answer works for me :)

Comment: You are welcome @Bry. Follow-up questions should be posted as new questions.

Comment: @Rubén I see alright created follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71942714/how-to-get-the-value-from-another-sheet-with-variable-sheet-name-and-rows-using