# How to get the value from another sheet with rows using Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In addition to the previous question [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71941024/how-to-get-the-value-from-another-sheet-with-variable-sheet-name-using-google-sh)

how to update for the next row?

In the image below the error will have this formula `=INDIRECT(TO_TEXT(D5)&"!$AB60")`. The row below the error needs to be `=INDIRECT(TO_TEXT(D5)&"!$AB61")`, same goes to the next row and so on...

How to improve this formula `=INDIRECT(TO_TEXT(D5)&"!$AB60")` to solve the problem.

AB60 will provide different value against AB61, AB62, AB63...

[image]

Comment: The formula shown is already what you want, right? If so, it's not clear what is the problem / being asked. P.S. While including a link to the previous question might be helpful, please bear in mind that each questions shoul be self-contained.

Comment: Not exactly because that (error in image) is for row 60, same formula but will need for each row. AB60 has different value vs AB61, AB62....

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain that and to include some sample data as text, not as image. Better if you include a [mcve].

Comment: Got it updated the Question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't have clear what is being asked. Please let me know if you add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=INDIRECT(TO_TEXT(D5)&"!$AB"&row())
```

if the formula is set to row#61, you will obtain what you expect

if not, add to row() a value that give you an offset

Comment: Yup, got would like to know some example of the offset you have mentioned. Because row#61 is not the exact where the formula is set (row#61 is ref on the other table).

Comment: share a spreadsheet !

Comment: no importance that the data is on another sheet, row() will just catch a number